# Plotly figure , how to delete data outside xlim/ylim?

Tags: python, plotly, limit, figure

A 3D plotly figure maintains all data outside the limits that we can set manually. The data is there "in memory" just not visible. How can we delete data outside limits "in memory" to reduce the weight of a possible HTML output file??.  Context: I have to create a lot of small maps from different zones of a HUGE map. So I thought to do a FOR loop and in every loop to create a copy of Huge fig (  fig_copy = go.Figure(HUGEfig)  ) and set the new limits on the copy, but the resulting HTML files are as heavier as huge fig because inherits all the data from him (I guess).